# How to add traces for AppDynamics

Tags: python, logging, appdynamics

I have a Python agent for AppDynamics and I would like to have a feature to send specific logs that I could read afterwards directly in AppDynamics.
That is, just some logs sent to AppDynamics that I would use to troubleshoot any issue.

How could I do that, and where would I read them within AppDynamics?

Answer (score 0):

The Python Agent does not have this specific ability, but there are a few options which may aid in your use case.

1. Use Log Analytics - requires an Analytics Agent (or a Machine Agent with the Analytics extension). Set config / log line format to parse log data into a usable format in AppD. Docs: https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/analytics
2. Use Custom Events - through hitting the Analytics Events API to store records in a custom schema. Could be used to store log lines. Docs: https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/analytics/adql-reference/adql-data/analytics-custom-events-data
3. Use Custom Extensions - custom scripting for the Machine Agent allows for arbitrary reporting of metrics under a host as "Custom Metrics". Not for logs specifically, meant for additional metrics. Docs: https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/infrastructure-visibility/machine-agent/extensions-and-custom-metrics

It is also worth noting that by default, stack trace / call stack information can be found within sampled snapshots - see https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/application-monitoring/business-transactions/troubleshoot-business-transaction-performance-with-transaction-snapshots